# Is it possible to INNER JOIN 2 id's of a different type/values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, inner-join

As the title says, I am trying to `INNER JOIN` on columns that have different values/data types.

In one database table, let's call it Table A I want to do a select statement to get the values of a few columns (Subject, Name, Description, Date). Though I also want a relation name. The problem is however that the relation name (which is set in the relation table, Table B) is displayed in Table A as a string value (D0001001) - so not as a literal name.

To get the literal relation name there is a link with Table B that has an ID column 1001 - 1000~ and a relation 'literal' name column. So for example in table B ID 1001 matches company name MC DONALDS and in table A the RelationID is D0001001 (MC DONALDS).

Don't ask me why the RelationID in table A is with the weird D000 in front of it,  I don't know either but it had some functionality.

So back to the problem. I want to get a few fields from table A but also the literal relation name from table B where it matches the table A relationID values.

So the question is, how can I `INNER JOIN` on these 2 different values/types? `RelationID` in table A is of string type (`nvarchar` to be precise) and in Table B the `ID` that matches the relation name is an `Integer` type.

I thought I could fix it by:

1. Do a LIKE statement in the query where the ID of table B (1001 integer) partly matches the RelationID of table A (D0001001 string). This however didn't work
2. do a `REPLACE` statement by replacing the RelationID 'D000' values by nothing: "". This would probably still require some sort of cast to integer for the table A value. Had some error here probably because of a syntax error.

What I have so far:

```
SELECT 
    TableA.subject, TableA.Name, TableA.Description, TableA.Date, 
    TableB.RelationName 
INNER JOIN 
    TableB ON TableA.RelationID = TableB.ID
```

This returned a conversion that isn't possible (string / integer).

So then I tried:

```
SELECT 
    TableA.subject, TableA.Name, TableA.Description, TableA.Date, 
    TableB.RelationName 
INNER JOIN 
    TableB ON TableB.ID LIKE '% TableA.RelationID  %'
```

This didn't work either (EOF).

To make it a bit clearer my tables:

**Table A**
    +------------+-----------+------------------+---------------------+-----------+
    | RelationID |  Subject  |   Description    |        Name         |   Date    |
    +------------+-----------+------------------+---------------------+-----------+
    | D0001001   | Fast Food | Some description | Name of form filler | 13-3-2015 |
    | D0001002   | Drinks    | Some description | Name of form filler | 10-3-2015 |
    | D0001003   | Cars      | Some description | Name of form filler | 7-3-2015  |
    +------------+-----------+------------------+---------------------+-----------+

**Table B**

```
+------+--------------+
|  ID  | RelationName |
+------+--------------+
| 1001 | MC DONALDS   |
| 1002 | COCA COLA    |
| 1003 | MERCEDES     |
+------+--------------+
```

--> INNER joins in ID and RelationID

Any alternatives? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you may use the 'like' constructor

Comment: What will be the value of `RelationID` after `D0009999`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To escape from the convertion error remove the first characters in `RelationID` using `Substring` then `convert` the `RelationID` to `INT` then `JOIN` with the `ID` column in `tableA`

```
SELECT TableA.subject,
       TableA.Name,
       TableA.Description,
       TableA.Date,
       TableB.RelationName
FROM   tableA
       INNER JOIN TableB
               ON CONVERT(INT, Substring(TableA.RelationID, 2, Len(TableA.RelationID))) = TableB.ID
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! And everyone for that matter! Will test it asap.

Answer (score 1):

> Do a LIKE statement in the query where the ID of table B (1001
>   integer) partly matches the RelationID of table A (D0001001 string).
>   This however didnt worked.

Try the other way round:

```
SELECT TableA.Subject, 
       TableA.Name, 
       TableA.Description, 
       TableA.Date, 
       TableB.RelationName 
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.ID LIKE '%' + CAST(TableB.RelationID AS NVARCHAR(50)) + '%'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TableA.subject, TableA.Name, TableA.Description, TableA.Date, TableB.RelationName1
FROM TableA -- insert this line here
INNER JOIN TableB 
ON TableB.ID LIKE '%TableA.RelationID%'
```

In order to make your second query run you need to insert the from clause.  Unless this was a mistype on upload that should make it work, although it may not give you exactly what you want.

If the RelationalID column always has the same addition I would consider just cutting it out of the string.  With something like:

```
ON TableB.ID = RIGHT(TableA.RelationalID,4)
```

SQL should do the conversion from string to integer for you doing an implicit cast in the comparison.  If not just add the cast statement:

```
ON TableB.ID = CAST(RIGHT(TableA.RelationalID,4) AS INT)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `LIKE` in the `INNER JOIN`, but this gonna slow down performance of your Query, since `LIKE` sometimes prevents efficient index usage.